# Configure auto logout in apache shiro

Tags: session-timeout, shiro

I need to auto Logout a user when he leaves the web application for a certain period. I am using Shiro's DefaultWebSessionManager.

```
<bean id="sessionManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager">
    <property name="globalSessionTimeout" value="1800000"/>
</bean>
```

Currently with this configuration - Logout only happens when we make server request after a period of in-activity. Is there a way to auto-logut after the timeout period so that it doesn wait for a server request, just signs off automatically after a period of inactivity.

Comment: Do you actually want the front-end to automatically log out? In normal circumstances you will always need a http request from the user and then it checks whether it is timed out or not, so what you describe is normal behaviour. Are you looking for some sort of push logout mechanism?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a push logout mechanism

Comment: Well then the question really depends of what kind of front-end technology you use and it isn't really related to shiro.